# How do I resize a UIView so it fills the content of a UIScrollView when using a UIPageControl

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UIScrollView` with a `UIPageControl` in which I am showing a `UIView` (I've extended this in order to draw a graph) and a `UITableView`. When I first build this it works correctly for the size of phone that I built it in Interface Builder but the sizing doesn't work correctly on other phone sizes. The UITableView size correctly but not he UIView

I have looked online for solutions - implementing `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and resizing the contentSize of the `UITableView` is what got the `UITableView` working correctly but did not fix the `UIView`. 
Here is the code from my view controller.

```
class ProgressViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!
@IBOutlet weak var graphSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var chooseButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

private var toolBar = UIToolbar()
private var picker = UIPickerView()

// this is an extension of UIView
private var graphView: GraphView! 
private var tableView: UITableView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollView.frame.size.width * 2.0, height: scrollView.frame.size.height)
    scrollView.delegate = self


    graphView = GraphView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: scrollView.frame.size.width, height: scrollView.frame.size.height))
    graphView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    graphView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    scrollView.addSubview(graphView)

    tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: scrollView.frame.size.width, y: 0, width: scrollView.frame.size.width, height: scrollView.frame.size.height))
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tableView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: CELL_ID)
    tableView.register(DataHeader.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: DataHeader.reuseIdentifier)
    scrollView.addSubview(tableView)

}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollView.frame.size.width * 2.0, height: scrollView.frame.size.height)
    tableView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollView.frame.size.width, height: scrollView.frame.size.height)
    graphView.frame.size = CGSize(width: scrollView.frame.size.width, height: scrollView.frame.size.height)

}
```

Here are images of what I see.

[image: GraphView which extends UIView - not wide enough]
[image: UITableView correct size]

What changes do I need to make to get my GraphView (extends UIView) to fill the scroll views content whatever the size phone thats being used ?
(I am using Swift 5 )

Comment: set constraints to width be equal to scrollview

Comment: Thanks will try. Never setup constraints in code before ... so may take a little figuring out

Comment: The GraphView width was correct but the UITableView was overlapping it. Seems the UIScrollView width changed after the TableView frame was set in viewDidLoad. So by setting it in viewDidLayoutSubviews I fixed the problem. Not sure it's the right way but seems to work. The line I added:          tableView.frame = CGRect(x: scrollView.frame.size.width, y: 0, width: scrollView.frame.size.width, height: scrollView.frame.size.height)

Answer (score 0):

replace this one and check

```
graphView = GraphView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: scrollView.frame.size.height))
```

Comment: Good spot. I forgot to remove that - it me experimenting to see whether the setting in viewDidLoad mattered once I'd added viewDidLayoutSubviews - it didn't make any difference. Removing the '*1.5' makes no difference. Will edit my question

Comment: thanks - tried your suggestion but it made no difference

Comment: Have you added the paging enabled ==>  scrollview.isPagingEnabled = true

Comment: yep I have paging enabled set to true. The paging works. Just when it's different size phones the GraphView size isn't changing - it's still the size that's sets using the constraints in IB and for that phone size.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. In case you're interested. Adding the following to viewDidLayoutSubviews fixed it:         tableView.frame = CGRect(x: scrollView.frame.size.width, y: 0, width: scrollView.frame.size.width, height: scrollView.frame.size.height)

Answer (score 0):

Try to start using constraints :) it will make your life easier and you won't need to calculate the content size.

```
class ProgressViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet private weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet private weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!
    @IBOutlet private weak var graphSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet private weak var chooseButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet private weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

    private var toolBar = UIToolbar()
    private var picker = UIPickerView()

    // this is an extension of UIView
    private let graphView: GraphView = {
        let graphView = GraphView(frame: .zero)
        graphView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return graphView
    }()
    private let tableView: UITableView = {
        let tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero)
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return tableView
    }()
    private let stackView: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView(frame: .zero)
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.axis = .horizontal
        return stackView
    }()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupScrollView()
        setupTableView()
        setupStackView()
    }

    private func setupScrollView() {
        scrollView.delegate = self
    }

    private func setupTableView() {
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

    }

    private func setupStackView() {
        scrollView.addSubview(stackView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor)
        ])

        stackView.addArrangedSubview(graphView)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(tableView)
        setupStackSubviewConstraints(views: [graphView,tableView])
    }


    private func setupStackSubviewConstraints(views: [UIView]) {

        views.forEach {
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                $0.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.heightAnchor),
                $0.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor)
            ])
        }
    }
}
```

Check out this version of your controller :) and try to figure out how the constraints work. I've added a horizontal stack view into the scroll view because it makes it easier :) and it aligns the subviews automatically :) you just need to provide proper constraints to them :)